# chrome extension get number of open tabs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension that has a button with different functions.
So I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve number of tabs that are open and
in my content.js I want to execute different thing when clicking the button depending on how many tabs that are open.

Been trying different approaches with chrome.tabs.query in background.js and sending it back but having troubles since it's asynchronous.

**content.js**

```
     if (tabcount < 2) {
    $(function () {
        $("#Back").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();
        });
    });
    console.log("one tab");
}

if (tabcount > 1) {
    $(function () {
        $("#Back").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = 'exit';
        });
    });
    console.log("more tabs");
}
```

**Edit:** added message code

Background message code

```
function sendMessageToTab(tabId, message) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, message, resolve)
    })
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.query({ windowType: 'normal' }, function (tabs) {
            const msg = tabs.length;
            sendMessageToTab(tabs[0].id, msg)
        });
    } return true;
});
```

content recieve

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {

        if (request > 1) {console.log('more than 1 tab open'); }

    });
```

Comment: Why asynchronous code is a problem? Simply put this code inside the callback and use the result there.

Comment: I get The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: Reverse the direction: use sendMessage in the content script and onMessage in the background script.

Comment: but how will I know that a tab has been updated, chrome.tabs.onUpdated is only available in background right?

Comment: There's no need for onUpdated because your content script runs automatically when the tab is loaded.